# How to deploy GoLang Binaries to CF

Tags: go, cloud-foundry

Hi we are trying to deploy golang binaries to cf.

for example main.exe which is in /deploy/ folder along with mainfest file

**Note**: It is also observed that if we push the whole project app then it works. but if we try to push only binaries then we get the below error

[image]

And Manifest file contains following info

```
 applications:
    - name: test-app
      command: test-app
      env:
        GO_INSTALL_PACKAGE_SPEC: ./



**ERROR** To use go native vendoring set the $GOPACKAGENAME
          environment variable to your app's package name
          **ERROR** Unable to determine import path: GOPACKAGENAME unset
```

After adding GOPACKAGENAME: main since main.exe is our binary name we get following error below

```
  Failed to compile droplet: Failed to run finalize script: exit status 12
   Cell 507b6e9c-c5c5-4685-9a71-d7cc1c876f5a stopping instance 6a92ff73-76ec-4baf-8a3e-54b54cfa307e
BuildpackCompileFailed - App staging failed in the buildpack compile phase
```

Comment: Crosscompile to linux/amd64 and use binary_buildpack.

Comment: it works with  https://github.com/cloudfoundry/binary-buildpack.git, thank you:)

Comment: Golang buildpack is used when you push whole project = CF will compile own binary. I would say that will be better, more native approach.

Comment: FWIW, the `cfml` tag should be removed as it refers to the "ColdFusion" language and not "Cloud-Foundry" (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks @Volker for pointing out

for above issue:

first we have to build with following command (used make file)

```
GOOS="linux" go build main.go
```

then copy that main binary to /deploy folder

then manifest file in the deploy folder

```
applications:
    - name: test-app
      command: ./main
      stack: cflinuxfs3
      buildpacks:
        - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/binary-buildpack.git
```

Then to push to cf

```
cf push -f ./manifest-template.yml
```

Comment: It is better to specify also architecture `GOARCH=amd64` for `go build` explicitly (otherwise you can expect problems if you are not compiling on amd64 architecture).